# SQL Pivot to display users questionnaire responses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I am running the following SQL statement

```
SELECT
 su.Id
  ,rp.QuestionId
  ,rp.AnswerId
FROM SiteUser su
  JOIN Response rp ON su.Id = rp.SiteUserId
  JOIN Answer an ON rp.AnswerId = an.Id
```

Which results in the following ouput

```
UserId    QuestionId    AnswerId
--------------------------------
1         1             1
1         2             6
2         1             2
2         2             3
3         1             2
3         2             2
```

I would like to achieve the below output

```
UserId    Question1   Question2
-------------------------------
1         1           6
2         2           3
3         2           2
```

Can anyone help with writing the Pivot statement?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? Pivot operator is vendor specific.

Comment: Will there always only be two possible questionIDs? There is a way you can write it dynamically to be able to handle any number of questionIDs.

Comment: There is actually 10 questionIds. It is always worthing know how to write it dynamically. Any thoughts

Comment: @SeanDooley I added in my answer how to perform this dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you haven't mentioned any RDBMS, this query below will work on almost all RDBMS.

```
SELECT  su.Id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rp.QuestionId = 1 THEN rp.AnswerId ELSE NULL END) Question1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rp.QuestionId = 2 THEN rp.AnswerId ELSE NULL END) Question2
FROM    SiteUser su
        INNER JOIN Response rp 
            ON su.Id = rp.SiteUserId
        INNER JOIN Answer an 
            ON rp.AnswerId = an.Id
GROUP BY su.Id
```

Comment: you're welcome! but hey, what RDBMS you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? etc.. `:D`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an RDBMS with the `PIVOT` function  (SQL Server 2005+/Oracle) then you can use:

```
select Id, [1] As Question1, [2] as Question2
from
(
  SELECT su.Id
    ,rp.QuestionId
    ,rp.AnswerId
  FROM SiteUser su
  INNER JOIN Response rp 
    ON su.Id = rp.SiteUserId
  INNER JOIN Answer an 
    ON rp.AnswerId = an.Id
) src
pivot
(
  max(AnswerId)
  for QuestionId in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

If you are using SQL Server an you have an unknown number of values for the question id's then you can use dynamic sql to get the same result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(QuestionId) 
                    from Response 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsFinal = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(QuestionId) + ' as Question'+QuestionId 
                    from Response 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @colsFinal + ' from 
             (
                SELECT su.Id
                  ,rp.QuestionId
                  ,rp.AnswerId
                FROM SiteUser su
                INNER JOIN Response rp 
                  ON su.Id = rp.SiteUserId
                INNER JOIN Answer an 
                  ON rp.AnswerId = an.Id
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                max(AnswerId)
                for QuestionId  in (' + @colsPivot + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```